# How to add callback to JSON request response?

Tags: php, json

I'm displaying images from JSON, since some lines doesn't have any image url attached:

```
echo "<p><img src='".$offer['mobile_app_icon_url']."'></p>";
```

Some images appear as `:null` instead of URL
How  do i add a callback to convert `:null`into `/images/image.png` to load custom image instead ?

Response example:

```
"mobile_app_icon_url":null,"
"mobile_app_icon_url":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com//UB5a8qPFoYonW8BT_zJiwtTEZVoVuWFwEzo4bvj0NrrKg3SCSdzIaBCmhDNI8M1lOq8=w100",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by this:

```
$x = (array)$offer['mobile_app_icon_url'];
if (empty($x)){
echo "<p><img src='images/icon.png'></p>";  
            } else {
            echo "<p><img src='".$offer['mobile_app_icon_url']."'></p>";    
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

**I answered before you update your question, maybe now this is not appropriate**

You could do something like this :

```
echo "<p><img src='".$offer['mobile_app_icon_url'] ? $offer['mobile_app_icon_url'] : [link_to_your_default_image]."'></p>";
```

It's a ternary condition it's like a compact if/else. So if **$offer['mobile_app_icon_url']** is set // not null , it will be used, or else **[link_to_your_default_image]** will be used.

Here is a documentation on the [ternary condition](https://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators)

Comment: This have messed everything.

Comment: How has this messed everything? what was the result?

Comment: img src appeared as a link, not an image, custom icon didn't appeared either.